# Server management software that can serve Ruby-Rack applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, rack, cpanel

I need a cPanel alternative, but with easy deployable Ruby-Rack applications support, not only Rails.

Heroku just started to fail hard, after cedar, for me. Their downtimes are greater than my computers downtimes for June. So it is not an option anymore.

Or maybe an open source suite that is easy to modify you can suggest?

Comment: This question is off-topic here as well as on Server Fault per the respective FAQs (cf. no product or service recommendations). That said, you might want to have a look the Chef/Puppet/cfengine family of tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [OpenShift](https://openshift.redhat.com/app/). It's a PaaS system, similar to Heroku, that's open source.

Comment: awesome, i'll just wait for a few more answers

Comment: I can second that. Openshift is also on github with all the necessary information to get started with your own stack: https://github.com/openshift

Answer (score 0):

I've heard good things about [Interworx](http://www.interworx.com/) which can host Ruby apps as well.